# How to avoid the toast when screen is on landscape mode in Android

Tags: android, orientation, toast

I need to show the user a message using toast or snackbar. However, i do not want to show this message when the user tilts his/her phone into landscape mode. How can I achieve this message showing only in portrait mode and not in landscape mode?

Comment: Test the orientation of the device before calling Toast.show()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will return `true` if the phone is in portrait and `false` if the phone is in Landscape it uses configurations:

```
private boolean isPortrait(){
   return (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Import configuration classes in Android Studio its easy. So from here you can use a simple if statement using the method given above:

```
if(isPortrait()){
    //Show you Toast and snackbar here
}
```

For more information on this [check the official documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can check orientation of the phone in resources configuration object:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

When it equals `ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` simply don't show the toast/snackbar

For the reference see:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation

Comment: Thanks. I just realized what kinda stupid question i asked.